# Log4net use the same appender config in xml to log to multiple files

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-appender

I have in my config this appender:
`appender name="TC3DataLogger" type="Intel.STHI.Device.ContextLog.TC3DataLogger" >
    <file value="null" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Once" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="100MB" />
    <datePattern value="-yyyyMMdd-HHmm" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <header value="Date, CS, FeedbackInput, PWM_Duty_Cycle (Cold='-' Hot='+')&#13;&#10;"/>
      <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}, %message%newline" />
    </layout>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
      <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
      <LoggerToMatch value="Intel.STHI.Device.ContextLog.TC3DataLogger" />
    </filter>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
  </appender>`

I need to simultaneously log to multiple files. I create each log file this way:

```
public void CreateNewLogFile(string FileName)
    {
        IAppender[] appenders = LogManager.GetLogger(TC3Logger.GetType()).Logger.Repository.GetAppenders();

        foreach (TC3DataLogger rfa in appenders.OfType<TC3DataLogger>())
        {
            rfa.File = FileName;
            rfa.MaxFileSize = MaxFileSizeKB;
            //sub system that the configuration for this appender has changed. 
            rfa.ActivateOptions();
            TC3datalogRFA = rfa;
        }
    }
```

Now every time I create a new log file, all my other loggers, log to this file. How can I simultaneously log to the different files?
I tried this:

```
public void WriteToLog(int CSNum, string Message, string LogfileName)
    {
        if (!TC3LogsDictionary[CSNum].Logging) return;
        TC3LogsDictionary[CSNum].TC3datalogRFA.File = TC3LogsDictionary[CSNum].LogFileName;
        TC3LogsDictionary[CSNum].TC3datalogRFA.ActivateOptions();
        TC3LogsDictionary[CSNum].TC3Logger.Info(CSNum, Message);
    }
```

But I get new files every time I try to log to the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to log to different files would be a feature of a specific appender. You seem to be using some kind of custom appender and I have no idea whether this appender has that feature.  I don't think either of the standard log4net file appenders can do this.  You could create your own appender by creating a class that inherits from `Log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton` there is a tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/406634/Creating-a-custom-log-net-appender) that gives an example of how to do it.